# SSRS Bar Chart : The Labels are shirinking

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]

Hi, 
Can anyone suggest me the solution for the problem iam facing in my SSRS Stacked Chart, the labels for very small values are not displaying properly.

**Soution I have tried** :

I have tried the Series Property Setting the Label position to Bottom,Top,Outside etc.  
I have also tried setting the Interval from Auto to a value as low as 5 but still the labels haveing value 1,2,3 are not displaying properly.

Please help !

Comment: change the label font size / color, you cant do much with these built-in features

Comment: Your labels aren't shown because they are white font on a white background and there isn't enough value in the series for the bar to serve as the background. You can add a **Background Color** to the Label or change the **Color** of the label to something other than white.